# checking the index of a list according to similar items within the list and then append into another list based on the dimension of the list

Tags: python, list

[Updated]
Recently, I am trying to find the index of a 2D list. For example, I have an input as below:

```
a =  [["text", "man","chest","funny"],["cruel", "jut","for","teting"],["I", "take","this","for"],["learning", "purpose","only","please"] ]

b = [["text", "funny"], ["cruel"],["I", "take", "for"],["learning", "purpose"]]
```

I tried to find the index that have the similar items for both `a` and `b` by using the code below(The indent might be wrong due to copy and paste, please adjust accordingly):

```
store = []

for i in a:
    for u in i:
        for ii in b:
            for uu in b:
                for iu in uu:
                    if iu in u:
                        store.append(i.index(iu))
```

Somehow, my output became something like this:

Output now:

```
store = [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I dont get how come it has so many of the similar index appearing.

Since it was supposed to be a 2D. May I know whether is there a way to make it be like this:

Expected output:

```
store = [[0,3],[0],[0,1,3],[0,1]]
```

Please assist me in solving this issue. Thank you

Comment: Is there anyone who can assist me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it.

```
store = []  
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    store_x = [] 
    for i,xx in enumerate(x):
        if xx in y:
            store_x.append(i)
    store.append(store_x)
```

and a hard to read one liner using nested comprehensions

```
store = [[i for i,xx in enumerate(x) if xx in y] for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

In case `b` is only a list of strings, instead of a list of lists, instead of iterating through `a` and `b` simultaneously you can just iterate through `a` alone:

```
store = [[i for i,xx in enumerate(x) if xx in b] for x in a]
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. this is what I want it to be. But I also have another method which I edited above. Could you tell me why it happened like that if possible? Thank you so much.

Comment: One thing is you only ever append integers to the list in your attempt, but you want a list of lists, so you have to make a distinct list as you iterate through each element of a.

Comment: you also iterate into b too deeply. I think your code is considering things like `if "text" in "funny"` inside the conditional

Comment: Now I get it. Oh yeah, I am testing on another one more thing, if you are free could you shed some lights on this too? what about if my b = ["text", "funny", "cruel","I", "take", "for","learning", "purpose"]. If this was the case, how should I change the code to? Thank you for your time

Comment: so b is only a flat list, but a remains a nested list?

Comment: Hi sir, I think there is one problem here. It seems like the output I received is a little wrong. store = [[0, 3], [0, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1]]... somehow there wasnt supposed to have [0,2] but [0] only

Comment: can't really understanding without seeing the data. What happens when you run `x[1][0] in y[1] and x[1][2] in y[1]`? This code assumes that y is a list of lists. If y is only a list of strings, what happens when you run `x[1][0] in y and x[1][2] in y`?

Comment: Im sorry for misleading you. I meant for the second part where the b is considered to be a flat list. When that happens, somehow [0,2] is stored.

Comment: Try running this: (I made a mistake in the previous comment)

`a[1][0] in b and a[1][2] in b`. Does it return `True`?

Comment: Yes, it returned True.

Comment: afaik this verifies that your data `a` and `b` support that value of the list.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. I misunderstood just now. haha